# Set Image Opacity Problem

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, mouseover, opacity

I have a little design problem.

On [this page](http://www.woonbel.nl/registraties/registratie.php) I have a couple of mouseover images.
As you can see (only in IE) the images are circled with black when setting the opacity.

I do not have this problem in firefox.

The reason I use opacity, is because when I use hide/show the image, the table where it resides in gets shaky.

Can anyone help resolve this problem?

Thanks, Richard

Comment: If you find my answer as correct, you can mark it as an answer, so that other users facing the same problem can know (and I can get some extra rep points :))

Answer (score 2):

That's quite a hack you are using. Ideally, you must hide/show the images on mouseover/mouseout like this -

```
document.getElementById("imageId").style.display = "none"; //Hide
document.getElementById("imageId").style.display = ""; //Show
```

If this makes your table ***shaky***, then there has to be some problem with the table structure you are using on your page (I don't see any problem in the table structure on [the page](http://www.woonbel.nl/registraties/registratie.php) tho).

To circumvent this problem you can also use the `visibility` class like this (instead of using `display`) -

```
document.getElementById("imageId").style.visibility = "hidden"; //Hide
document.getElementById("imageId").style.visibility = "visible"; //Show
```

Comment: Dave, whether to set the value of the "display" property to "" or "block" depends on whether the element was displayed in block mode or not before being hidden. If it was not displayed as a "block" element, and then you set the value of "display" property to "block", it MAY mess the layout in FF (I've seen some cases).

Comment: Opacity is definitely the wrong way to go here.  In IE, Opacity is currently implemented as a DirectX filter, which is rather expensive and has quirks.